# Symfony 2 acl isFieldGranted throws exception

Tags: symfony, acl, symfony-2.3

I'm busy implementing ACL on Class + Field (classFieldAce) level within my application. Everything seems to work fine, but I am getting unexpected behaviour from the isFieldGranted() method from the ACL. Here is my code:

```
// setup ACL
$className       = 'Acme\Model\Junk';
$oid             = new ObjectIdentity('class', $className);

try {
    $acl  = $aclProvider->findAcl($oid);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $acl  = $aclProvider->createAcl($oid);

    $roleUser  = new RoleSecurityIdentity('ROLE_USER');
    $mask      = new MaskBuilder(4); // 4 = EDIT

    $acl->insertclassFieldAce('name', $roleUser, $mask->get());
}

$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

so far so good. I assign the role "ROLE_USER" to my user. Now I want to run some checks (manually as I am creating a service). Here is the check code (inside controller for now):

```
// check the ACL
$className       = 'Acme\Model\Junk';
$oid             = new ObjectIdentity('class', $className);
$aclProvider     = $this->get('security.acl.provider');

try {
    $acl             = $aclProvider->findAcl($oid);
} catch (...)
```

all good. Now the stuff I want to check:

```
$sids = array();
foreach ($this->getUser()->getRoles() as $role) {
    $sids[] = new RoleSecurityIdentity($role);
}
$masks = array();
$masks[] = MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT;

if ($acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NOT ALLOWED";
}
```

At this point everything is working, I get the output "OK". The only thing I am a bit uncertain about is the very roundabout way of sending the $sids to the check - so my first question would be if there was a quicker way other than manually building the list.

Things start to go "wrong" (as in unexpected) when I try and check for a higher mask:

```
$sids = array();
foreach ($this->getUser()->getRoles() as $role) {
    $sids[] = new RoleSecurityIdentity($role);
}
$masks = array();
$masks[] = MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER;

if ($acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NOT ALLOWED";
}
```

rather than returning false, $acl->isFieldGranted throws a NoAceFoundException.

Am I going about the field check the wrong way, or should I just catch the exceptions here?

**Update: added logs:**

check code changed to:

```
    $this->get('logger')->debug('XX: ACL retrieved, checking field grants');
    try {
        if ($acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids, true)) {
            $this->get('logger')->debug('XX: ACL OK for field :name:');
        }
    } catch (NoAceFoundException $e) {
        $this->get('logger')->debug('XX: ACL NOT OK for field :name: NoAceFoundException thrown');
    }
```

When the check is successful, the logs are as follows:

```
DEBUG - SELECT o.id as acl_id, o.object_identifier, o.parent_object_identity_id, 
o.entries_inheriting, c.class_type, e.id as ace_id, e.object_identity_id, e.field_name, 
e.ace_order, e.mask, e.granting, e.granting_strategy, e.audit_success, e.audit_failure, 
s.username, s.identifier as security_identifier FROM acl_object_identities o INNER JOIN 
acl_classes c ON c.id = o.class_id LEFT JOIN acl_entries e ON ( e.class_id = o.class_id AND 
(e.object_identity_id = o.id OR e.object_identity_id IS NULL) ) 
LEFT JOIN acl_security_identities s ON ( s.id = e.security_identity_id ) WHERE (o.id =16)

DEBUG - SELECT t0.name AS name1, t0.roles AS roles2, t0.id AS id3 FROM staff_group t0 
INNER JOIN rel_staff_staff_group ON t0.id = rel_staff_staff_group.group_id 
WHERE rel_staff_staff_group.staff_id = ?  Context: ["242"]

DEBUG - XX: ACL retrieved, checking field grants

DEBUG - XX: ACL OK for field :name:
```

When the check fails, the only change is this line (I compared the logs in two browser tabs)

```
DEBUG - XX: ACL NOT OK for field :name: NoAceFoundException thrown
```

There is no difference in logging between

```
$acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids)
```

and

```
$acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids, true)
```

Update 2:

I opened a bug report in Symfony and it has been resolved https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9433

Comment: @freetrace thanks for the suggestion; updated question, but didn't get much from the logs

Comment: ok. Try to insert this `var_dump($acl->getClassFieldAces('name'));` before your `$acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids)`.

Comment: here you go http://pastebin.com/RPddrX4P .

Comment: Could it be a bug in the ACL system?

Comment: Indeed a bug, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you must to catch `NoAceFoundException` in your code and throw `AccessDeniedException`:

```
try{
    if (!$acl->isFieldGranted('name', $masks, $sids)) {
        throw new Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException();
    } 
} catch (NoAceFoundException $e) {
    throw new Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Because:

> The first applicable ACE will make the ultimate decision for the
>   permission/identity combination. If it is granting, this method will
>   return   true, if it is denying, the method will continue to check the
>   next   permission/identity combination.   This process is repeated
>   until either a granting ACE is found, or no   permission/identity
>   combinations are left. Finally, we will either throw   an
>   NoAceFoundException, or deny access.

So if `MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER/RoleSecurityIdentity($role)` combination has not found `NoAceFoundException` will be thrown. For detailed see [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Domain/PermissionGrantingStrategy.php) line 137.

Comment: Thanks for researching. To be honest I find it strange because a boolean TRUE/FALSE is much quicker to check than a TRY/CATCH block.

Comment: @mogoman I'm agree with you. This is strange and I'm don't understand why they throw an Exception instead simple FALSE.